# Most effective way to generate random 3D objects?

Tags: javascript, random, graphics, 3d, three.js

I am currently trying to write a program using three.js that will generate novel 3D blocks such as [this](https://sketchfab.com/models/29f283eb4ac04a27bfbd71e571263c4e). As you can see, the model is made from relatively very simple geometric figures. I've considered everything from randomly appending primitives to each other to using machine learning data (just a thought). What are your thoughts on this? So far, I am leaning towards the former.

On another note, do you think it would be more wise to use geometries from three.js's stock, or to generate points and connect them with lines?

Comment: I would start with the provided ones, which will get you up and running faster. you can swap out and do the point thing later, and still keep everything else you worked on. don't even bother with AI

Comment: Totally depends what you want to achieve. Procedural generation of 3D objects is a super cool research topic though. Read some papers to get ideas. Here is one for procedural generation of architecture: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.87.8244&rep=rep1&type=pdf